Design and communication between microservies
To learn about things like microservices, messaging brokers and all other new and fancy things, I decided to create microservices that will let me monitor my base within Minecraft (done via ComputerCraft HTTP API) from web browser (I will figure out frontend later). I don't want to create another online shop, which is perfect for it, with 0 challenge.
I'm unsure how to properly solve communication between them. A practical example would be communication between mass storage, a service that will be responsible for controlling resource generation, and something else that can boost said resource generation, let's call it "Magical Service" and let's say it uses mana.
Mass Storage will receive info on what items I have stored.
Magical Service will receive info on mana reserves and will decide if more mana should be generated.
Resource Generation will decide if some resource should be generated and if mana should be used to speed up the process (Maybe mana boosting should be part of Magical Service?).
How do I inform Magical Service about amount of stored fuel for mana generation?
How should Magical Service inform Resource Generation if it's safe to use mana for boosting generation?
How do I tell Resource Generation how much of some resource is in Mass Storage so it can decide if it should generate more?

There will be a few services like Mass Storage, let's call them Core Services, that will need to somehow "share" it's information with other services. Another such thing would be power generation.
How do I handle a situation where most of the peripheral services will require some information from one or more of such Core Services without turning this whole thing into monolith?


To learn about things like microservices...

You should probably review You Want Modules, Not Microservices by Ted Neward.  Which is to say, for a "toy" project, you'll probably have an easier time if you first concentrate on figuring out the correct logical boundaries within a single running process, then after that start thinking about how to move (some of) the capabilities into separate processes.
A good starting point for the microservices part might be Micro services - Java, the Unix Way by James Lewis.  In particular, pay attention to the "interesting non functional requirements" that get called out for some of the elements in the design.
Given that you are just starting out, the lessons of Microservices for Greenfield may be useful.

I'm unsure how to properly solve communication between them.

Ideally, you do it by passing messages around, usually via some form of "dumb pipe".  That doesn't necessarily mean that you need to have multiple web servers running in your single process, but you probably should have some form of dumb "request/response" capability and some form of dumb "pub/sub" capability that you can use to create logical isolation of the modules from each other - with the processes copying information to and from data structures "owned" by the dumb pipe abstraction.
(I'll note in passing that these messages shouldn't include references to domain objects, but only information - no shared mutable state across logical boundaries.)
What you may find, as you start working within these constraints, is that your initial guesses about service boundaries weren't very helpful.  That's great, welcome to the learning curve.
As far as I can tell, the processes for identifying microservice boundaries aren't really all that different from the processes for identifying service boundaries (a la "service oriented architecture"), so pay attention to the logical boundaries of "business capabilities" in your domain to make sure that your factoring is reasonable.  Udi Dahan's Finding Service Boundaries, Illustrated in Healthcare might be a useful start.

Thanks, those are very good sources of info. What I'm struggling to figure out is how to handle messages, as they sadly can't be as stupid as I would like, kind of. My mass storage will receive a bunch of data in a request from the game, which I then need to filter out based on what each service needs, and ideally I wanted those services no not know much about each other, or ideally nothing at all, since I imagined them as not being pull packet but rather deployed on demand where player can decide to not deploy something they don't need.

Observer seems good, as sub could also contain a list of "filters", but how to tell mass storage where should it respond to? In theory, I could do use RabbitMQ/Redis/etc and do a kind of sub/pub where each service has its own queue and when resource generation service sends a message to mass storage queue it passes both filters and id of its own message queue so mass storage would know where to send response, but is it good approach? It would work, but might be a bit anti-pattern.

You phrase you question in terms of microservice communication, but it seems like the real problem is how to process a decision.
Under some conditions you want the GenerateResouces action to be run. But that has various prerequisites and options. I would suggest you look at Goal Orientated Action Plan https://goap.crashkonijn.com/introduction/theory, or Action Lists or similar
The idea is simple, you make a list of actions with dependencies and the AI loops through them starting with the goal action, checks to see if it can be done, if not it checks the first dependency action and so on until if finds one that can be actioned. eg (you are gona test my minecraft knowledge now)

smelt iron (has ore, has coal, furnace exists)
put ore in furnace (furnace exists, has ore)
build furnace (furnace !exists, has stone)
get ore from store ( store has ore)
mine ore and put in store

If you don't need a generic way to handle multiple tasks you can just hard code this somewhere. Then each step calls your various microservices to check its pre conditions or to perform tasks

Microservices should own their own data.
However, in order to do this and communicate with other Microservices, they need to know about some data in other Microservices. This is typically done via natural keys.
Taking the canonical example of customer, order and product.

The order service will need to know the customer id and product id and will thus have that in its data store.
This makes it easy to then reference customer and product Microservices once you have an order id.
While such data stores are autonomous, co-ordination across them can be a challenge. If say, a product was discontinued but a customer had placed an order for it, there should be some sort of event that allows the order to be flagged somehow so the customer can be informed.
N.B. It can be tempting to put all data into a regular database and then share that. This is an antipattern - you're coupling your Microservices to a data store that contains data you don't need to know about and potentially creating a single point of failure. It would also violate the Microservices principle of autonomy.

So in my case and in above example Resource Generation should "tell" Mass Storage that it wants to know how much of item X I have and every time Mass Storage has its counts updated it should broadcast it to every service that is interested in it? That sounds like ideal case for Observer pattern.

Yep, that sort of thing. I was thinking Hollywood Principle, but yeah - there might be multiple parties that need to know if a product was discontinued in the example above.

In my case mass storage will hold thousands of items and liquids, I will also potentially have multiple of those "non-core" services so notifying everyone about everything is not really feasible. I thought about observer because that would allow me to pass some sort of filter in subscribe, that I could use to match items against and then just respond with everything that passed said test. Unless you have better idea on how to handle that?

Just trying to figure out the flow (don't know Minecraft - sorry). So if a POST to Mass Storage or Magical Generator happens you ultimately want Resource Generation to send Minecraft a message if it has enough of each of a given item, enough mana to generate the resource and any extra mana to speed up generation of that resource?

Let's say that my goal is to have about 5000 of something. If I go below that then generation should start, but if I go below 3000 It is way too low for me, and if I have enough mana stored to boost production of that resource it should be boosted.

Minecraft in this case can be equated to real life (with some leeway here and there). I want to always have 5t of gravel in my warehouse, and if it dips below that, turn on the rock crusher. If the amount of that gravel dips below 3t then I clearly use lots of it and I need to give that rock crusher way more power, so I check my nitrous oxide reserves and if I have enough I want to use it to power up rock rusher engines.

Assuming these are autonomous services, then under what circumstances could the "order service" ever proceed autonomously of the "customer service"? Why are these things so complicated that they require two independent services?

@Steve Within Minecraft it makes sense. What I want to create is a set of services that will allow players to "check" their in game base and save time by not forcing them to build the same setup a few times just because they want to scale up resource generation.  It will be aimed at players with modded games, which also means that I have to support any modpack available. By making services more autonomous, potential user will be able to mix and match them to fit his needs.

@RobbieDee because I forgot to mention you in my response.

@user2463506, I'm not sure if I'm wading into something that is highly Minecraft-specific (of which I have no experience), but my experience of customer-facing ordering applications is that they usually depend on the maintenance of a customer list which determines things like the authority to place an order, keeps account of invoices and payments, that kind of thing. Autonomy and avoiding unnecessary coupling is always a good thing if it's free, but my understanding is that there is no decoupling between customer and order data (in typical applications where both concepts actually exist).

@user2463506 Ah, OK - makes sense. In that case it sounds like you need 3 Microservices. Those being Inventory, Mana & Generator. When Inventory is changed, it checks mana level and calls Generator if needed.

@user2463506 N.B. in your diagram, you have HTTP verbs but I think you were talking about message bus initially. Which of these you go with (event or REST) will have a bearing on the design too.

@Steve In the diagram I was just explaining how data stores are connected. No operations between these Microservices is inferred for the sake of this example.

@RobbieDee Normally calling Generator that then calls minecraft should happen, but in my case it's impossible. ComputerCraft only allows for Post and Get, which means that I basically have web browser, something similar to web browser called Minecraft and my services that are something like some crossbreed between MITM and adapter. Thats the best analogy I have.
